# вставить переменную в атрибут ,jq

Tags: jquery

```
     $("document").ready(function() {
          var a = 3;
            $('#inp1').attr('oninput', '$(\'#inp2\').val(parseInt($(this).val()) + ( ',a,'  * $(this).val())/100) ');
 });
```

код, который автоматически передает значения с одного инпута в другой , делая со значениями некоторые матем. манипуляции.
Одно значение должно браться из переменной 'a', т.к. я планирую его менять при нажатии на кнопки. 
Вопрос в том, как это сделать? так, как я указал, не работает, хотя во всех источниках написано что это делается так. Спасибо

Comment: Покажи html свой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 3;
  $('#inp1')[0].oninput = function() {
    var value = +$(this).val();
    $('#inp2').val(value + (a * value) / 100);
  };
});
```